# 1st word 1st character 2nd word 2nd character and on till the end of array

Tags: javascript

```js
 words = [
    "January", 
    "lacks", 
    "caveats", 
    "hazardous", 
    "DOORS",
    "crying",
    "arrogantly", 
    "climate", 
    "proponent", 
    "rebuttal"
    ]; // answer Has to be JavaScript 
        // i can only get it right till JavaS

function decode(words){
   
     for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        msg = words[i].charAt(i);
        
        while(i>6 && i<=words.length){
            j=0;
            msg = words[i].charAt(j);
            j++;
        }
        console.log(msg);
    }
    
    
}
decode(words);
```

```
J
a
v
a
S
g
n

t
```

For the 1st word, grab the 1st character, for the 2nd word, the 2nd character and so on. When you get to the 6th word, start from the 1st character again.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` gives you the remainder of the division of i for 5.
0%5 = 0,  1%5 = 1,  ...,  5%5 = 0 and so on..

```
function decode(words){
     for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        msg = words[i].charAt(i%5);
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```